# IronSpeed Error: Invalid Parameter in KeyValue.ColumnValueByName()

Tags: record, editing, ironspeed

I am developing a website with IronSpeed. A colleague made changes to the database. On getting to the code, I get the error: IronSpee Error: ***Invalid Parameter in KeyValue.ColumnValueByName()*** when I attempt to edit a record.

How can I sort this out?
Thanking you,
Simon.

Answer (score 1):

You could have saved yourself a lot of time by just resyncing the database schema.  Iron Speed would have picked up on the added or missing fields and no rework would have been necessary.

Comment: That is the correct way. Downvoted Simon's own answer

Answer (score -1):

We had to delete the entire module(aka Show, Edit and Add pages), then recreated them with the help of the Application Wizard. This wizard can be accessed through Tools>Application Wizard menu.

References: http://sjc.ironspeed.com/post/IronSpeed-Error-Invalid-Parameter-in-KeyValue.ColumnValueByName%28-%29-6265041

Hope this will be helpful to someone in future.